# Convert Word document [Multi Page] into JPEG File in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, ms-word

I want to convert the contents of word file [3 or 4 page document] into JPEG file in C#.

I have tried using clipboard option, but it is converting only the first page. Please help me.

Comment: Perhaps there is a reason you must use JPEG, however you should be aware that other file formats (e.g. PNG) will provide smaller filesize AND higher quality from a typical word document -- unless the document itself contains high-colour images.

Comment: Artelius is exactly right. Jpeg creates artifacts compressing text that PNG or GIF will not.

Answer (score 2):

i think that [ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) can output jpeg

so the process would be:

- first configure a postscript printer (print to file as the printer port)
- print the msword document to a postscript file
- process that file with GhostScript, you have many output options here

you can code the whole thing in C# [here is a wrapper for ghostscript in c#](http://www.mattephraim.com/blog/2009/07/08/introducing-ghostscriptsharp/) ... and you could use COM interop to work with msword

this solution isn't the best for a public webserver though, as it would require msword to be installed

i have worked with excel before in this way (through COM interop on a webserver) to extract data ... but that was on an internal company webserver

Comment: Thanks for the reference to my project!