# convert the contents of word file to JPEG in c#

Tags: c#

I want to convert the contents of word file [single page] into JPEG file in C#.

Follwing is the code I have tried. But the Clipboard.GetImage() returns a null.

Please help me out.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        object fileName = @"C:\Documents and Settings\ErabLK\Desktop\toTest.docx";
        object val = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object falseVal = false;
        Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref val, ref falseVal, ref val, ref val,
                             ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val,
                             ref val, ref val);


        wordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
        wordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
        Image img = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetImage();
```

Comment: JPEG seems like a very unusual format for storing computer-generated content.  It's best for photographs.  Have you tried using Word export functions such as print to pdf?  Would creating a pdf instead of a jpg work for you?

Comment: Thank You for reply. What I need to do is to load the docx in a PictureBox. And the requirement says not to use pdf because the user must have pdf reader installed to view it. 

So only option left is to convert it to jpg. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

GetImage() will only work if there is something on the Clipboard that is an image already.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getimage(VS.80).aspx

One solution I can think of is to create a Bitmap and use the **System.Drawing.Text** functions to render the pages text to the Bitmap and save it as a JPEG. You can probably extract the font properties from the word document and use that for the drawing to render it with a similar look.

Comment: But the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373073/convert-word-document-multi-page-into-jpeg-file-in-c says that he has converted the first page using the Clipboard option.

Comment: Can you please direct me to initial posts on rendering word pages to Bitmap.

Comment: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-how-to-draw-text-on-an-image has some decent examples. That was one of the top results when searching for system.drawing.text like I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. I will try using the methods u mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

        object falseVal = false;

        object fileName =@"C:\u.doc";
        object val= System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc1 = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref val, ref falseVal, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val);

        wordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
        wordDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.
        Image img = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetImage();
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.